# Is it possible for terraform to authenticate with the azure storage container using the service principal credentials rather than access keys?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-blob-storage

I have a Service Principal which is a Data Blob Contributor in a certain storage container. I checked and I can upload/download/delete blobs in that container with Azure CLI using the `--auth-mode login` parameter without passing the access keys.

However, when I run `terraform init` with the same service principal targeting the same storage container I get this:

```
Initializing the backend...
╷
│ Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: Error retrieving keys for Storage Account "app541certfremotebackend": storage.AccountsClient#ListKeys: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailed" Message="The client '53bfcd5f-0906-4043-bda0-84cacf6ce9d0' with object id '53bfcd5f-0906-4043-bda0-84cacf6ce9d0' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/listKeys/action' over scope '/subscriptions/4...d/resourceGroups/a...2/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/a...d' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."
│
│
╵
```

Using the access keys requires us to grant the Service Principal a role that would contain the action `Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/listKeys/action`. The closest built-in role would be [Reader And Data Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#reader-and-data-access).

I really do not like it, because then with the access key would it not be possible to access all the storage containers in the storage account?

Is it possible to make it work without the access keys by leveraging the RBAC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, this is the classical RTFM moment. According to https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/settings/backends/azurerm I can set `use_azuread_auth = true` in the backend config.

I tested it and it really works.